# howto serve different local index page with multiple virtualhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, localhost

**Objective**: do http://test.local and get the index from testsite, do http://l4.dev
and serve the index from lara4.

What I don't want is the first index from the virtual host listing it can find

**How should multiple local sites be managed**? - best practice - (*apache version 2.2*)

This Is what I added to the httpd.config
(is this the best way, - to add it directly to httpd.config?)

```
   NameVirtualHost *:80

 <VirtualHost *>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/redres/Webdev/lara4"  
    ServerName l4.dev
    ServerAlias www.l4.dev
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/redres/Webdev/testsite"  
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias www.test.local
</VirtualHost>  
<VirtualHost *>   
    DocumentRoot "/Users/redres/Webdev"  
    ServerName localhost  
</VirtualHost>   

<Directory "/Users/redres/Webdev">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

this is the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   test.local
127.0.0.1   l4.dev
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

thanks

Comment: Can you resolve l4.local? dig any l4.local

Comment: yes, but that only proves it takes the first vhost it finds, changed it to l4.dev

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache setup for multi-sites](http://serverfault.com/questions/279047/apache-setup-for-multi-sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a NameVirtualHost directive:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/redres/Webdev/lara4"  
    ServerName l4.local
    ServerAlias www.l4.local
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/redres/Webdev/testsite"  
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias www.test.local
</VirtualHost>  
<VirtualHost *>   
    DocumentRoot "/Users/redres/Webdev"  
    ServerName localhost  
</VirtualHost>   

<Directory "/Users/redres/Webdev">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/de/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: I did that, quickly edited the question! - no luck

Comment: You will have to do it exactly like I wrote. If you use `NameVirtualHost *:80`, you also have to use `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

Comment: thanks, I just found out myself, but great fot noticing, it works now. Should I move this block to extra/httpd-vhosts.config?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Apache which virtual host should be used for a given domain name, by adding the additional hostname as a `ServerAlias` to the virtual host.

Comment: I did that just now, it did not work - still goes to folder lara4

Comment: So post the new config and maybe someone can see what you did wrong.